# How can I access a many to one relationship primary key value from the template?

Tags: python, django

I have a many to one relationship with an Item model, and a Book model which is a type of Item.  The Item has a primary key, and the Book has a primary key, and also a foreign key which is an item_id.

I run a complex query on the SQLite db, using inner join, to retrieve all data from Item as well as all data from Book.  What results from the query, among other data, is two pks as ids: one from the Item, and one from Book data.  In SQLite the heading for the Item pk is 'id' while the heading for the Book id is listed as 'id:1'.

In views, I run the query to collect the objects into a book_qs queryset.

In the template I try to loop thru the queryset to retrieve and display the value of the objects in a table.  Because there are two ids or pks, one for Item and another for Book, I cannot figure out how to retrieve just the Book id pk which is labelled as id:1 from the queryset.  Id returns the Item id.  At times in the loop, I only want to retrieve the Book id, but I need to loop thru the book_qs to show other data as well in the table.

```
mydata['book_qs'] = Item.objects.raw('SELECT  * FROM item INNER JOIN book ON item.id = book.item_id WHERE item.title = %s', [user_input]);

return mydata
```

```
{% for myitem in book_qs %}
    {{ myitem.id:1}}
    {% endfor %}
```

The code results in a template syntax error.

Comment: So if `Book` has a ForeignKey to `Item` why don't you just do `qs = Item.objects.filter(title=user_input).prefetch_related('book')`. Also your queryset is a list of `Item`, not `Book`. And each `Item` can have many related `Book`. So you probably need a double for loop, inside the item for loop, `{% for book in myitem.books.all %} ... {{ book.id }} ...`

Answer (score 0):

In the view Just use

```
book_qs
```

to store the returned data and make a dictionary like this:

```
d={'book_qs':book_qs}
```

and pass it to template

```
return render('abc.html', d)
```

in the template do like this:

```
{% for item in book_qs %}
    {{item.id}}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: In the view just use book_qs by mistake I typed book_qs'

Answer (score 0):

Because the number of "many" classes in the many to one relational db were several, and my db entries were still tests at this point, I decided to go back and revise the models to include an explicit primary key name in each model, making those autogenerated ids easier to access from the template.
Ex.

```
book_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
```

therefore

```
{% for myitem in book_qs %}
   {{ myitem.book_id }}
{% endfor %}
```